# Is a 1 GB sized USB stick big enough for Ubuntu 13.10 live system?

Tags: live-usb, 13.10

Can I use a 1 GB USB stick for the Ubuntu 13.10 release? I can't find my 2gb stick, but i want it now :)

I didn't try it yet, because I'm afraid I will screw up my laptop.

Comment: **Yes** it will. If the Ubuntu ISO-file fits on the USB-Stick it will work.

Answer (score 3):

The 13.10 ISO is 883MB so 1GB is enough.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes.

1 GB is more than enough to create a live USB.

All desktop variants of Ubuntu flavour ranges between 880-895 MB. So, you should be very well covered.

```
ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso  881M  Desktop image for 64-bit Mac (AMD64) computers (standard download)
ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso      883M  Desktop image for 64-bit PC (AMD64) computers (standard download)
ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso       895M  Desktop image for PC (Intel x86) computers (standard download)
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:  yes.  If the ISO fits on the USB stick, so will the extracted ISO.  You won't have a lot of room for persistence, but it'll work fine.

As far as "screwing up your laptop..."  You can't screw your laptop up with a live image (without *really* trying, anyway :), even if the image is mis-copied or otherwise corrupt (as it would be with a small USB drive).  The image is its own self-contained OS.  So worst case, Ubuntu won't boot, but your computer should be fine.